# How does Linux know which USB hard drive is which?

Tags: mount, hard-disk, automounting

Currently I have [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) installed on my PC with a USB hard drive partition mounted as `/home`. This is working well.

If I install a second USB hard drive, is there any chance Linux will get confused between the two, and try mount the second hard drive's partition as `/home` on boot? That would be bad.

Coming from Windows, I've seen it happen often that drive letters are not "remembered" correctly causing all sorts of issues.

I guess the main question is: How does Linux actually know which USB hard drive is `/dev/sdb` and which is `/media/misha/my_2nd_drive`?

Comment: *with a USB hard drive partition mounted as `/home`* Can you please explain how you did this?

Comment: I did it during Linux Mint installation. At that point it's quite easy. My SSD appeared as **sda** and the USB hard drive appeared as **sdb**. I put `/` and `swap` on **sda**, and `/home` on **sdb**. But I wouldn't know how to *change* an existing installation's `/home` mount, too new for that!

Comment: The answers say what you **should** do, but I don't think they directly say that `sd[a-z]` are simply named in detection order.  No attempt at all is made at keeping the names the same.  It's typically deterministic (same kernel on same HW will give the same naming), but a new kernel with an update to the SATA-controller driver could make it scan the SATA drives in the opposite order.  Instead of even trying to rename block devices (as is done with `nameif` or w/e for ethernet device names, usually with udev rules), UUID, label, and id (by drive serial num) names exist.

Comment: I've seen servers with SAS disks where rebooting would usually lead to a different ordering of `sd[a-z]`: the probing of disks is done simultaneously (in parallel) and whatever disk happens to be detected first becomes `sda`, etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usually the location of the USB port (Bus/Device) determines the order it's detected on. However, don't rely on this.

Each file system has a **UUID** which stands for *universally unique identifier* ([FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) and [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) use a slightly different scheme, but they also have an identifier that can be used as a UUID). You can rely on the (Linux) UUID to be unique. For more information about UUIDs, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Use the disk UUID as a mount argument. To find out what the UUID is, run this:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
```

(`blkid` needs to read the device, hence it needs root powers, hence the `sudo`. If you've already become root, the `sudo` is not needed.)

You can then use that UUID in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
UUID=7e839ad8-78c5-471f-9bba-802eb0edfea5 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

There can then be no confusion about what disk is to be mounted on /home.

For manual mounting you can use `/dev/disk/by-uuid/.....`

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even know about `fstab` until now (that's how new I am to Linux). I've looked at my `fstab` file and everything is already identified by UUID. The Linux Mint installer did good.

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining briefly what the UUID is, and why it's unique which make it a reliable identifier.

Answer (score 11):

If your `fstab` references partitions as `/dev/sdx`, then adding a new drive can certainly confuse the system. The recent practice, however, is to use [Partition UUIDs](https://wiki.debian.org/Part-UUID) to identify the partitions.

If your system has `udev` installed (must be the case for 2.6+ Linux kernels), you can use persistent naming in `fstab`. By default, partitions are identified via UUIDs:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/31f8eb0d-612b-4805-835e-0e6d8b8c5591
```

You can, however [create a meaningful partition label](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-partition-howto-set-labels/) like "home" and reference your partition like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/home
```

Those IDs can be used as a replacement for `/dev/sdx` in `fstab`.

Comment: I wish I could mark your answer correct too. Wurtel was in a touch earlier. But thank you anyway, you get my +1.

Comment: @misha256 The irony is that I don't even use UUIDs on my systems (because the output from `df` and `mount` becomes unreadable). Internal HDDs have quite high chances of being detected first, and in the same order every time.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I think that must only have been true when UUIDs were first introduced. My `/boot`, for example, is identified by UUID in `/etc/fstab`, but it appears as `/dev/sda2` in the output from both `df` and `mount`.

Comment: @seumasmac I use Debian oldstable which probably explains the difference.

Comment: If you use labels, you can use `LABEL=home` in your fstab.  I like to use labels like `t-home` for the home directory on my machine called tesla.  So if I stick the disk in another system, there won't be two filesystems with the same label.  This is why Linux installers generate random UUIDs and use them in fstab, instead of having default labels that would give most systems the same labels for their FSes.  @misha256, you might want to think about this if you label your FSes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I do indeed use labes, and I have a naming scheme aimed at making these labels unique.

Comment: UUIDs are great and work as noted in the answers. But, they are not human friendly. Whenever I create partitions (anywhere), I give them unique human readable labels that make sense to me. This is especially helpful when writing backup scripts dealing with several drives. You don't want to get a source and destination reversed by accident! Also, whenever you reformat a partition, it gets a new UUID and you have to edit anything that used that UUID, whereas you can still use the same label as before and not have to change anything.